# EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, .net

I have migrated my project from **EntityFrameWork 6** to **EntityFrameWorkCore 2.0**.
but while migration by command dotnet ef migrations add init , it gives me error.

```
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
No DbContext was found in assembly 'Huddle.Wrapper.Admin'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.
```

can anyone plz help ?

Comment: Hello, do you have EntityFramework assembly added as a Reference (or even better, as a Nugget package)?

Comment: @DavidHruška No I have not added EntityFrameWork package , I added EntityFrameWorkCore instead

Answer (score -1):

When you want working with EF Core, I think you should install package **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**

Comment: The OP indicated that they have already added the EntityFrameworkCore package

Comment: have you already configured the dbcontext definition at Startup.cs file  inside ConfigureServices method ?